# Check logon rights of user in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

How to check that some user has logon rights ?
I want to show current logon right and allow other user to enable to disable it.

Something like

```
IF pg_can_login('someuser')
  ALTER ROLE someuser NOLOGIN;
ELSE
  ALTER ROLE someuser LOGIN;
ENDIF
```

How to implement pg_can_login(user) in SQL or in plPgSQL  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accessible through [pg_roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-roles.html)

```
select rolcanlogin
from pg_roles
where rolname = 'someuser';
```

Comment: Thank you. Some login roles contain õäüö lowercase characters. I tried ˇupper(rolcanlogin)ˇ  but those are not converted to ÕÄÖÜ . Database locale is estonian and for CHAR column values UPPER() works properly. Also `LOWER(rolcanlogin)` works poperly converting other characters to lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  IF (select rolcanlogin from pg_roles where rolname = 'aklaver') THEN
     RAISE NOTICE 'yes';
  ELSE
     RAISE NOTICE 'no';
  END IF;
END;
$$
;

NOTICE:  yes
DO
```